# IBM Mobilefirst MFP_PERSISTENT_DATA table

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In IBM Mobilefirst database table **`MFP_PERSISTENT_DATA`**, ID field is the same as parameter **`client_id`** in VALUE field.

What exactly does this **`client_id`** means? When and how is it generated? If mobile application does not have any authorization, how is this **`client_id`** is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client_id is the identification of the end user. MFP server uses this as the index key for MFP_PERSISTENT_DATA table in order to get the correct data for the end user.
It is generated by the server during the registration process (which happens the first time a client accesses a protected resource in the MFP server).
As far your question about how client_id is used if the app has no authorization, and by that I assume you mean that there are no security checks and resource is unprotected - it is not used since the registration process will not happen.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer in the IBM MobileFirst Foundation team.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, idohu! Yes, mobile application has no security checks at all - for testing purposes. In this case, will MFP server generate new ID each time this same application on a same device connects to MFP server?

Comment: It will NOT generate any ID's because the client will not go through the registration process.